# How to see the Domain Group's members?

Tags: groups, domain

There are two types of groups. They called Domain or Sharepoint groups. I cannot see the member's of Domain Groups. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Domain Groups is Active Directory groups.
In case you need just to see their members then use `Active Directory Users and Computers` windows feature (you may need to install it).